# What is the right way to include a wp-admin file in your theme?

Tags: theme-development, wp-admin, include

I'm trying to use `wp_delete_user()` in my theme, to allow a user to delete their account from the front-end.

Turns out that the `wp_delete_user()` is not defined unless /wp-admin/includes/user.php has been included.

Is there a *right* way to do this in WordPress? Something that uses get_bloginfo() or a global constant for example?

Comment: Please describe your project in more detail and explain the context. My gut reaction is that there is no right way to include admin files in the theme and that you should probably be using some other approach-- possibly the AJAX API.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add `require_once` statement at the beginning of your `functions.php` file:

```
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/user.php';
```